# lightSlider: make slider still moving with same speed

Tags: html, css

I am using lightSlider and I would like to make it sliding all the time still with same speed. And without "stop" or "pauses" between images. Just run still with one speed.
Is possible to do it with lightSlider? Or is there better "slider js library" to do this thing?

Code:

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#lightSlider').lightSlider({
        item:4,
        loop:true,
        auto:true,
        slideMove:1,
        easing: 'linear',
        cssEasing: 'ease',
        speed:100,
        controls:false,
        pager:false,
        adaptiveHeight:false,
        responsive : [
            {
                breakpoint:800,
                settings: {
                    item:3,
                    slideMove:1,
                    slideMargin:6,
                  }
            },
            {
                breakpoint:480,
                settings: {
                    item:2,
                    slideMove:1
                  }
            }
        ]
    });  
  });
```

Comment: I mean moving like that: https://jsfiddle.net/nvLb5e6j/

Comment: Here is demo for lightSlider: https://jsfiddle.net/5e95zaej/
thank you

Comment: Thank you! One question, why couldn't you use a marquee?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code. set pause to 0. I hope it helps.

```
 $("#lightSlider").lightSlider({
     pause: 0
});
```

Comment: I was thinking the same but it makes slider "buggy", see how: https://jsfiddle.net/qe2k0bp5/

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered if you set the pause and the speed to the same value it seems to work and move in a continuous motion.

```
speed:2000,
pause:2000,
```

However, it still seems buggy when you set:

```
loop:true,
```